# Deleting rows with a specific criteria

Tags: r, delete-row

I have data set up like this:

```
date     ID   weight    
Apr 4    1    21
Apr 5    1    22
Apr 6    1    23
Apr 4    2    30
Apr 5    2    31
Apr 6    2    32
Apr 7    2    12
```

I want to go in and figure out cases in which the last noted weight is not the maximum for that ID. So in the example above the last row is the highest date for `ID=2` but not the highest weight for that ID.

I can set up a for loop that basically spits out a data frame with the weight of the max date and the weight max within the ID and I can do a difference score. Anyone with a difference score of greater than 0 needs the row with the last date removed.

```
subs <- levels(as.factor(df$ID)) 
newdf <- as.data.frame(rep(subs, each = 1))
names(newdf) <- c('ID')
newdf$max <- NA
newdf$last <- NA

for (i in subs){
  subdata = subset(df, ID == i)
  lastweight <- subdata$Weight[length(subdata$ID)]
  maxweight <- max(subdata$Weight)
  newdf$max[IDdate$ID == i]<-maxweight
  newdf$last[IDdate$ID == i]<-lastweight
}

IDdate$diff <- as.numeric(IDdate$max) - as.numeric(IDdate$last)
```

Now what I'm struggling to do is come up with a solution that would allow me to take the IDs where `diff>0` and go into the original data frame and delete the last date for those IDs.

I have tried `which` and `subset` but this is not quite what I want.

Comment: What if you delete the last row and then your _new_ last row for that person also satisfies the criteria for deletion? Should it also be deleted, or are you only deleting at most one row per id?

Comment: this is basically for cleaning up a dataset, if an ID has a weight lower than the maximum for that ID it is an error and needs to be discarded before analysis, so yes, after the first go around nothing gets deleted.

Comment: @user1558387, note that `subdata$Weight` returns `NULL` if the original column name is `weight`.

Answer (score 1):

I like to approach these problems in two steps.  First, write a function that does what I want it to on a single group (assuming your data is sorted by date):

```
df2 <- df[df$ID == 2,]

myfun <- function(x) {
  # if the maximum weight value isn't found on the last row,
  if (which.max(x$weight) != nrow(x)) { 
    # return the data.frame without the last row:
    return (x[-nrow(x), ])
  } else {
    # otherwise, return the whole thing:
    return (x) 
  }
}

myfun(df2)
```

Then you can use that function in any number of the "split-apply-combine" packages:

### plyr

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(ID), myfun)
```

### data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, myfun(.SD), by=ID]
```

Comment: thanks for the tip! i can't seem to get the function to work and i'm too new to be able to break the function down

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  On your data set, this function removes the single row from the second ID that is too small and returns the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter:

```
DF[as.logical(with(DF, ave(weight, ID, FUN=function(x)
    ifelse(seq_along(x)==length(x), x<max(x), TRUE)))),]
```

It will remove the last row (grouping by ID) if its weight is not the group maximum.

Comment: this doesn't seem to do it, because when i run the loop on the new data set, i'm not getting all diffs of 0

Comment: this seems to delete the last row if it is also the max.

Comment: @user1558387 nope, the last row only drops if its weight is strictly less than the maximum. Note condition `x<max(x)`. Consider editing your question; your objective is not totally clear.